# How can we make dumbfire rockets more accurate?

Tags: science-fiction, warfare, flight, rockets

I am using rockets as a main weapons platform for my vehicles. Currently they are fired from a railgun like apparatus. A rocket is at the center of three rails arranged in the fashion of a triangle. A sabot jacket surrounds the rocket, which is connected to the rails. The rocket motor ignites bringing it up to a maximum burn rate, after that the breaks on the rails disengage and the sabot jacket carries out it out of the rail system. The jacket separates and the rocket flies off to hit its target at an incredible speed. The rocket motor would still be active throughout the flight, stopping only if it runs out of fuel or hits its target. The sabot may rotate, as of now I'm not entirely sure if that would increase or decrease the accuracy of the weapon.

The weapon system will be firing both guided and unguided kinetic energy missiles. This question focuses strictly on the unguided solid rod penetrator rocket.

Kinetic energy missiles have a massive benefit in that they can accelerate to high speeds without using complex technologies that require advanced technologies seen in railguns, coilguns, combustion light gas guns etc. They also have a significantly higher upper velocity compared to the upper limit of chemical/gunpowder rounds. Outside of the initial acceleration phase, they greatly out speed even armor piercing fin stabilized discarding sabot rounds.

Interestingly enough the fuel needed to get such a weapon system to such speeds and velocities (1.5-2.23km/s) to kill in a small portable fashion was created during the days of the Future Combat System and 1980s-early 2000s. Several kinetic energy missiles were created, LOSAT, KEM, CKEM for reference. They observed excellent penetration powers during testing application against even ERA equipped T-72s. The minimum range of CKEM was 200m whereas LOSAT was 400m.

All my targets will be engaged at ranges of 1Km+ (maximum ranges for older kinetic energy missiles range between 5-10km using technology from the late 90s to early 2000s), and the maximum speed will be much higher due to in setting rocket fuel sources. The issue I have with such a system is accuracy. In the real world the situation was solved with active guidance. However, my rockets can't use active guidance for multiple reasons. Once it leaves the barrel, whatever direction its pointing at, is the direction in which its going to hit its target. Ideally the rockets should fly in a level trajectory. They won't be doing any maneuvers or top attack of any kind or use any chemical effect warheads (HEAT/HEAT-FS/HE/HESH/HEDP).

**What modifications would be needed to make such a rocket more accurate to be able to hit targets at long range (1-10km) without the use of active guidance?** Active guidance in this case refers to something like beam riding, warhead seekers, or radar guidance from a command vehicle.

I am okay with some "passive" guidance systems so long as they aren't actively scanning data from outside the rocket itself. For example, keeping track of a rockets angle of attack or speed would be considered "passive" in this sense since an onboard computer in the rocket can do this without having to communicate with a command vehicle. But an image/heat seeker would be considered active since its scanning target data to make major course changes instead of course correcting to its initial launch vectors. Preloaded data onto the rocket is fine to set information such as range, elevation, angle, etc. **The goal is to stabilize the rocket as much as possible so that it has a linear flight plan, based on the initial vector it left the barrel from.** In this sense the "unguided" rocket rounds act as tank rounds.

While active guided missiles are obviously better, they're also significantly more expensive and complex to mass produce. A "dumb" KEM would cut heavily on costs and past certain speeds would benefit from not having seekers/fragile electronics as they can be damaged by shock/trauma which KEMs are more than capable of doing on launch or even main boost phase.

Comment: You should do the maths to find out how long the barrel needs to be and how fast the missile needs to accelerate.

Comment: (a) Most of the first five paragraphs are irrelevant and make the question harder to read and understand. (b) A passive level-flight rocket is just a cruise missile relying on a gyroscope. (c) Rockets are more susceptible to climate than ballistic shells, which is why guidance is involved. (d) You don't want a linear flight path, otherwise you can only shoot line-of-site and a tree will stop your shot. Ballistic shells can be lobbed over hills. Depending on level flight means you can't do that with your rockets. (e) This seems like a really limited solution for so much technical precision.

Answer (score 3):

### Your rocket will never be as accurate as rifled artillery -- but it might not need to be.

First, drop the idea of brakes in the launch rail to let the rocket come up to full thrust.  Military rockets get full thrust instantly and plenty of velocity for basic fin stability in a tube barely longer than the rocket.  Thrust can be arbitrarily high (remember the Sprint missile system that could reach Mach 5 in a few seconds?), and smoothbore is the new normal for tank guns -- which, with computer targeting, are capable of hitting another tank at several kilometers even while the firing tank is moving fairly fast.

Where you have an accuracy limitation is the same place the 1960s vintage Gyrojet did: you're still thrusting after the rocket leaves the guide, and especially as you build velocity above Mach 1 (shockwave buildup at that speed can be very destabilizing).  That means that any disturbance of the rocket's heading after it's in free flight is *magnified* by continued thrust.

Spinning the rocket like a rifle bullet is the obvious solution (and it's the one that Gyrojet used), but it doesn't work as well as it would with a passive projectile; further, the spin rate required would require more of a solid "barrel" than a rail assembly.

Most of this is part and parcel of why rockets aren't a primary artillery weapon for ranges between direct fire and a hundred kilometers or so -- beyond that, they win because a gun can't shoot around a sizable fraction of the Earth, but a (large enough) rocket can (in large part, due to guidance that lets it build up most of its velocity after it's beyond the dense part of the atmosphere).

However -- at distances from 1-10 km (similar to tank-on-tank engagement distances) you don't necessarily need *extreme* accuracy.  Even a main battle tank is a pretty small target at 10 km, but a high thrust rocket that builds up its velocity within a hundred meters of so from the rail and then coasts can be approximately as accurate as fin stabilized sabot shells fired from a modern smoothbore tank gun.  Some twist in the rail would help ensure imperfections in fins or nozzle don't result in wide misses, but it need not be the high spin rate of a rifled shell.

Comment: Several things to add - not really a critique - to make answer better. The main problem with the rocket unguided kinetic missile is the lack of guidance - as mentioned - however, it's not really that much of a problem. Because the most instability is introduced in the breaking Mach 1 barrier, after that every conceivable parameter is getting smaller. So, if there can be a way found to guide and stabilize that rocket until it hits Mach 2, this is doable. But still I would go for saturation, as it won't be as precise, but OTOH this will be 2m, 60kg missile, hard to fire in salvos.

Comment: Problem is, if you're going to break even Mach 1 in the rail, you may as well have a gun.  The Stalin Organ fired all the tubes over a few seconds with only slightly smaller rockets, though they did have multiple tubes instead of a single rail.  Fresher is the Multiple Launch Rocket System, same basic idea.

Comment: Yeah, the difference is all the HVMs ever developed were guided. If it's guided, it is a terrific weapon - LOSAT tested was very effective in long ranges (compared to sabot round), and it was effective within 10km. And more powerful the further it had to go, obviously. Here requirement is NOT guided, and this is a serious limiting factor. see here for some references: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Dynamic-stability-of-unguided-projectile-with-6-DOF-Bashir-Khan/7b445071337800ff1568500d0ff4594cecbcfecd

Comment: Well, let's do a little BOTE calculation: if we can get the acceleration Sprint had (~100 G) it would take about 2/3 second to reach Mach 2 -- or roundly 215 meters.  Even Mach 1 would be 1/4 of that, just under 55 meters.  Not going to get that in the rail.  Guns typically give 1000+ times this acceleration in the barrel, hence can be reasonable length and give useful velocity.

Answer (score 1):

### For ranges under 10km, just use conventional cannons.

Conventional artillery can easily reach ranges of 10km.  Even WWII era tank guns like the Russian M1931/37 had a maximum range  of over 10km with a 100% target accuracy against tank sized targets at ranges up to 2km.  And this was only a 122mm cannon built with technology 50-60 years older than your setting.

The 105D main gun on the M60A3 is still 10-20 years older than your setting and reported to have exceptional target accuracy against a moving tank at ranges of 5km.  However According to [the account by this tank gunner](https://www.quora.com/How-accurate-are-modern-tank-guns), these cannons were accurate enough to headshot a deer at these ranges.  This is to say that the listed 5km maximum effective range has much more to do with still having enough kinetic energy to kill a tank than a question of accuracy.

That said, you could perhaps use the kinetic energy issue as an excuse to introduce [rocket assisted projectiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket-assisted_projectile). RAPs are typically used to extend the range of conventional artillery shells to distances in excess of 30km, but perhaps they could be repurposed to improve your armor busting on targets in the 5-10km range.  If you know that your shells slow down too much past 5km, to pernitrate a tank, then you could add a dumb rocket fuse that only engages after 4.5km of flight time. This way, your shell gets all of the accuracy of a normal shell at normal ranges, and only boosts to improve kill power at the longer ranges.  Accuracy might slightly decrease once you engage the booster, but at the point, you are already reaching past your effective kill range; so, if there is any tradeoff in accuracy, it might be worth it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Onboard accelerometers and internal map.**

The rocket starts with an onboard model of where it is and where its target is.  The model used by all the rockets could be updated from sensors on the firing platform, with the location of the target added to the model onboard the rocket right at launch.  Then accelerometers on the rocket measure the forces on the rocket after it is launched.  The computer uses those forces to map where the rocket is in its onboard model.  It gets no additional information from outside the rocket but corrects its course according to where it thinks it is.

You could do all of this with 20 year old tech.  It would not be that expensive.

I wonder if the accelerometer on a phone is good enough to serve in this role?

Comment: Simple beam-rider seekers can be pretty cheap.  Translating that into what direction it goes is the more expensive part.

Comment: Question asks for unguided as a cost saving measure.

Answer (score 0):

**Spin stabilization.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-stabilisation

Spinning a projectile stabilizes it via gyroscopic forces.  That is how rifling works.  Spacecraft are also sometimes spin stabilized.  Rockets too can be spun - this from a model rocket hobbyist page:

https://www.apogeerockets.com/education/downloads/Newsletter228.pdf

> But let’s go back to basics. What might be the reason  we want a
> rotating rocket? The answer is that it helps to  make the rocket fly
> straighter. Why is it that a rotating rocket flies straighter? That
> answer is found on page 183 of the book Topics in Advanced  Model
> Rocket by Mandell, Caporaso, and Bengen (www.
> apogeerockets.com/topics_advanced_model_rocketry.asp).  “A rapid roll
> rate makes a rocket “sluggish” in its rotational  (pitch and yaw)
> behavior, allowing it to respond more nearly  to the time average of
> disturbances than the individual  disturbances themselves -- and since
> the time average is  generally much less than any one individual
> disturbance,  this is greatly to the rocket’s advantage.” The book
> goes on  to say that when the rocket does react to the disturbance,
> that the amplitude of the oscillations are also lot lower. In other
> words, a rotating rocket doesn’t react very  quickly to disturbances
> and it also doesn’t swing very far in  response to the disturbances.
> This means that it just keeps  going straight, which is a good thing!

You could configure the fins on the rocket to induce spin.  You could spin the launch platform.

For novelty's sake, I propose that these rockets have metal collars.  Before launch the collars are spun up to speed.  The fast rotation of the metal collar will stabilize the rocket.  If the rotating metal collars are not exposed to the wind (inside the rocket body, or inside a plastic cover) they will not interact with the air and cause the rocket to yaw in flight.

Metal collars with plastic covers are cheap.  Your rotation apparatus can be something like an electric drill built into the launcher.  Collars could also be decorated with team colors or obscene drawings, or obscene drawings in the team colors.

Answer (score -1):

**Working Railgun**

> What modifications would be needed to make such a rocket more accurate to be able to hit targets at long range (1-10km) without the use of active guidance?

Of course the first modification you need is a functional railgun that is small enough to fit on a tank. This is a tall order considering the size of existing railguns.

[image]

The American Navy will have you believe their railgun can fire a 10kg tungsten projectile at 3kms that goes straight through a tank and then through the tank behind the tank.

**First Modification:** make the railgun a  few thousand times smaller to fit on a tank.

**Second Modification:** make it cost effective.

The Americans now claim to have stopped working on the railgun since the raily-ness was too expensive it didn't offer enough benefit compared to missiles and normal cannons. big railgun was never good at hitting big things cost effectively.  So your small railgun needs to be modified to hit small things without costing millions per shot.

**Third Modification:** modify either the railgun or missile to not be destroyed while firing.

The US only tried their railgun firing lumps of tungsten. They never launched anything with electrical or explosive components.

Once you have those three things, or even the first two, there is no need to use a missile at all. Just use a bullet.

> Outside of the initial acceleration phase, [missiles] greatly out speed even armor piercing fin stabilized discarding sabot rounds.

You are free to claim your railguns can fire bullets at  whatever is the max speed of a missile. These railguns are fictional and work by magic anyway. It makes no sense to restrict yourself to the speed of "existing" railguns.

Comment: Better go back and read the question again -- the propulsion of the rocket is by its own motor, the "railgun" is just a guidance rail to ensure the rocket has enough velocity for stability before it's "on its own".  Like a somewhat longer version of the tubes on a Stalin Organ or similar.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Oh that makes much more sense. PS I hate railguns.

Comment: IMO, a workable and practical railgun would be an excellent replacement for long range artillery -- ammo is no longer explosive and weighs half what it does now for several times as many shots (traded off against needing large capacitor banks and a lot of electrical power).  Rail weighs about 20% what a naval rifle barrel does, but may need to be longer.

Comment: @ZeissIkon It would be practical if only we could build it so it's practical.